# Alert when a question is closed as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send a Stack Exchange notification when a question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-a-stack-exchange-notification-when-a-question-gets-closed)

I asked https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/gmail-search-isunlabelled on WebApps, which was closed as an exact duplicate. The duplicate question was indeed a duplicate, and the answer there answered my question so I'm not complaining about the close. I am complaining about not being told about it. The "close as duplicate" essentially answered my question, or at least pointed me toward an answer, but it was never flagged up to me in the alert bar.

I should have received a notification that my question had been closed as a duplicate. This would have let me know that my question had been answered.

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) events.