# Use inbox notification for close/open related activities

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, closed-questions, global-inbox

When you get a comment on your question or answer, or when a comment @-mentions you, a red notification appears on the top bar inbox. When you get an answer to your question, a red notification appears as well. When someone edits your question or answer, you get a notification. When a question or answer earns a badge, you get a notification in the rep area. But when you get a close vote, or in fact your question is closed, nothing happens. (Re-opening, too.)

This is especially problematic when the close vote identifies a duplicate and adds a comment. There is no notification! This just happened to me on [Does using SSL mean you have to say your app uses Cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17982739/203458) and I have double checked my inbox to be completely sure there was no notification. I continually argue that marking a question a duplicate is a gift to the asker, who doesn't have to wait for answers, but now I discover the gift is not treated the way an answer or comment would be. That isn't right.

I propose inbox notifications (red) for the following occasions:

- a close-as-duplicate vote is cast and an auto-comment is added
- any close vote is cast and you have close vote privileges
- your question is closed and you have reopen privileges

I propose edit notifications (green rep area) for the following occasions:

- your question is closed
- your question is re-opened
- your question is deleted

This will improve the interactions users have with the closing system. I understand the philosophy of not notifying of negative events, but not all of these, not even all closes, are negative, and it is important for the asker to react to them.

Comment: I don't think "any close vote is cast" needs a notification, the others I agree with.

Comment: Notifications for a post being deleted has been brought up many times and has been rejected.  You haven't added any reasoning here to justify revisiting that.  As for closing/reopening a question, that seems appropriate.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft that question was in the days of the old notification system - a lot has changed since then. Also, it was only about closing and not about getting close votes.

Comment: That other question is still very active though. Also, I do not see that your additional requests make that feature request any more likely to be sucessful. Thus any answer applying to that question also applies here. This leads to unnecessarily redundant content.

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on both [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) and [reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402476/51) events.