# Should the "bounty ending soon" email contain a link to the question?

Tags: bug, bounties, email

I have found questions complaining and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) that the text should be different when there are no answers, questions objecting to even getting emails when bounties are expiring, complaints about duplicate bounty-related emails, but not this one. The email I just got looks like this:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!
>
> Your bounty on the question … \
>
> Thanks for putting a bounty on your question. It looks like there are still no answers yet. You should consider improving your question to attract more answers. Could you:

See that `\` ? I didn't edit that in, it was there. I think that:

- it should end the sentence, from other questions it should be "ends in x hours"
- there should be a link to the question

But instead there's just a lonely backslash.

Comment: The question, should it be relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191423/use-inbox-notification-for-close-open-related-activities

Comment: dammit! I used both search and the related questions list while asking! Is totally a dupe.