# In which way the OP is notified about close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I'm just curious (may be I'll get a pretty good conception right now ;-) ), in which way the OP's notified about a (pre-defined) reason I have selected for a close vote.

Would he/she see immediately what **my** choice was, or is the notification just about overall closing reason?

Comment: You aren't even notified if it is closed.See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191423/use-inbox-notification-for-close-open-related-activities for a feature request asking for that to change

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian That was, what I've been noticing of course! I wondered, if the OP might get a separate (private) notification about the other close vote reasons. I know that one always can inspect the currently applied close votes, but I cannot delve down into the _advanced_ reasons (at least for my own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the OP has the [privilege to see close votes,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) he can see the number of close votes next to the close button, and specific reason(s) by opening the close menu, like any 3k user can.

Additionally if the close vote is for closing as duplicate, the OP can see a box at the top of the question listing the possible duplicates. This also appears for flags, though, so it is not fully accurate for seeing close votes, but it does not require the privilege.

Once the question is closed, individual close votes cannot be seen and instead you can only see the box below the question mentioning the reason that most of the close voters picked. For off-topic close reasons many might be listed mentioning the close voters only after the reasons they had picked.

That said, there's **no inbox notification** (or any other direct notification) for anything closing related to the OP, they have to check for these signs themselves.

Comment: THX for the insight, I'll accept this.