# Clicking "answered" or "modified" when answers are paginated should go to the answer anyway

Tags: feature-request, answers, pagination

A high-traffic question ([The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review) ) showed up at the top of the questions list today with a new answer from a low-rep user.

[image: question block on main page]

Because I knew that question had a lot of answers, I clicked on the word <kbd>answered</kbd> to go straight to the answer. Instead I just found myself at the top of the question page. This is what happens on sites where I have a lower rep and can't see deleted posts; if I click answered for a deleted answer I just see the question. But I can see deleted posts on meta.

I found the answer eventually towards the bottom of page 2 of the 3 pages of answers. While questions whose answers need to paginate are a bit of an edge case, they are one of the times we need this feature the most. Please make it work.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313428/why-did-the-format-of-full-form-urls-to-answers-change?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment - I would not have noticed the dupe-vote without it. I've grrrr'ed about that before though. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191423/use-inbox-notification-for-close-open-related-activities