# Double tap doesn't auto-zoom anymore on mobile

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, google-chrome, android

When you double-tap on a paragraph on mobile the zoom changes to match the width of the paragraph.

After the site upgrade, when you double tap a comment on a question or answer, the zoom level remains unchanged.

Browser is chrome on nexus 4, if relevant.

**Update**

This question explains how to disable it: [How to disable double tap zoom feature in Chrome 30 on Android (Nexus 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789951/how-to-disable-double-tap-zoom-feature-in-chrome-30-on-android-nexus-10)

Probably the mobile version has a viewport set

Comment: Are you using the mobile skin, or the regular setup? The Meta mobile view was updated recently to include the new top-bar too, so what site are you looking at?

Comment: The new meta site. This is one link that does it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed/94400#94400. Edit: it doesn't work on stack overflow either

Comment: It does work for me, Chrome on iOS, mobile and full site skins.

Comment: I may be about to say something stupid but isn't that browser behaviour rather than stack exchange behaviour.  I don't think my (standard android) browser has ever behaved like that (it does however zoom in slightly on a double tap for seemingly no reason)

Comment: Still zooms for me on my Nexus 7

Comment: It seems to be a browser behavior we can't change - declining for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's just browser behavior. The mobile theme still specifies:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

So zoom should not be disabled. But tap to zoom is being [disabled in some browsers for better touch behavior](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away).

On a Samsung S4 mini, I can only pinch to zoom in Chrome, but also double-tap to zoom in the stock Chrome browser. In an old Chrome on an old iOS version, I can still double-tap to zoom as well.