# Why was my "newbie getting started" post deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I recently made a post on Stack Overflow that was kind of a "getting started newbie" question regarding XMPP and Google GCM servers. Someone gave me a vague answer and that was about all that happened. I came back later and the entire post had been deleted.

I have seen posts "closed" by your employees but never a post completely deleted. Why has this happened?

Comment: Which question? Can you link to the deleted one?

Comment: You can find a list of your deleted questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1058647) (only you and mods can see the page). There's probably a moderator message saying why it's deleted. Share us the url to the question so we can help.

Comment: This presumably happened because the OP didn't realize the question had been closed and needed attention. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/147247 for a request to prevent that.

Comment: Questions aren't closed by "employees". They're closed by community votes. Anybody over a certain reputation can vote to close a question.

Comment: @KateGregory: 9 days is a long time for the OP to come back and check on their post to see how it is doing.

Answer (score 18):

Your question was deleted by an automated process.

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)  The reason for this particular deletion is covered in Item 2, under the subheading **By the System:**

> The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) closed (not as a duplicate),
>   unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or
>   accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more
>   days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

Basically, if a new question gets closed, is not upvoted, and no effort has been made to improve it via editing within a few days, it is automatically deleted.