# Redundant 'closed without comment' issue

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

On Blender, we have a custom off-topic reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report and not an actual question. These should be [reported to Blender's tracker](http://developer.blender.org/) instead.

So when we use this reason we get something like this:

[image]

Is a comment really necessary in this case? It seems really redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant, because without the comment, the OP would get no notification of the closure. Though I think it would be much better to send them automatic inbox notification; there is an old feature request about that.

Comment: ... this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/

Comment: @900 If the OP recently posted the question and isn't checking, that's on them. If the OP posted the question a while ago, then it's not too important that they know it's closed.

Comment: @Emrakul I disagree with both points. After posting a question, I may have better things to do than revisit it: such as answering, editing and closing other questions, perhaps on another SE site. The purpose of notifications, like those for  answers or comments, is to let me spend time doing something more productive than reloading a page.

Comment: @900 When do you need to know when your question is closed? The only answer I can think of is: if you're looking for an answer. All other times are just information you can't really do anything constructive with.

Comment: @Emrakul I'd say, OP always needs to know about the closure, so that they can fix the issues given in the closure banner, if at all possible. The banner says: "here's what's wrong, fix this if you can". This is not the least important kind of message on the site, but it happens to be the only kind of message that  does not generate a notification.