# Account notification when question is put on hold/closed

Tags: support, notifications

Notification about a question being put on hold/closed has already [had a question and discussion period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/267587), and the [highest voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125882/267587) suggests that this feature has been implemented, will be implemented, or was intended to be implemented.

I haven't noticed such notifications, but the answer also suggested that such notifications are opt-in only.

I would like to opt-in for these notifications, but I cannot find this feature in my user settings.

Was this feature ever implemented, and if so how do I opt-in for these notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this has not yet been implemented, otherwise said question would have the tag [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Is there any way to check on the status of this feature request?  It seems to be at least 2 years old.  Not that I know how old current in-progress feature requests are, just curious if there's any way to check on it.

Comment: @Zibbobz: There is no certain way to provoke developer feedback that I am aware of. Putting a bounty on it ([which has already been done recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/93842/revisions)) or giving the ultimate argument for this feature in an answer might help though.