# Dupehammer creates and deletes a comment, causing notifications to go out

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, dupehammer

[The dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/202832) is a good system. But when a gold badge holder closes a question, a comment still gets created on the voter's behalf, even though it will be *immediately* deleted by the system due to the question being closed as a duplicate. This is contrary to what normally happens when a *moderator* closes a question - no comment is ever created or deleted.

This is problematic because the comment's creation (even though it gets deleted in the same instant) still causes notifications to be sent out:

- The owner of the question receives an inbox notification telling them that there is a new comment on their post, which doesn't actually exist anymore.
- Anyone viewing the question at the time [will be notified via web sockets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251439/new-comment-notification-appears-and-dissapears-when-dupehammer-marks-q-as-dupe) that there is a new comment on the question, only to have nothing new at all load when they click to load the new comments.

I propose that *all* binding close votes refrain from leaving a comment, not only those cast by diamond moderators.

Comment: That's odd. I didn't realize it created a comment that was instantly deleted...

Comment: @Braiam The problem is that I **am** getting notified...

Comment: @animuson Are you able to see your own deleted comments?

Comment: No, I looked up a random question on Stack Overflow that had been dupehammered. Sure enough, there was a comment created and deleted at the same exact time.

Comment: I'm saying that that's the expected behavior when an user mark a question as duplicated.

Comment: @Braiam There is an inconsistency here, though. This only happens for dupehammer users. When moderators close as duplicate, a comment is never created and a notification never generated. Tbh I don't see the point in notifying a user of a "new comment" that always gets deleted the moment it's created. Bit of a lie.

Comment: I believe that it also happens when non-gold badge users vote to close as duplicate

Comment: @SamIam the problem is, with gold badge users it's completely superfluous...

Comment: @animuson And I don't like it. As said by Shog, if you are not notified that your question has answers somewhere else, how will you check? Will you keep refreshing the page for 2-3 hours waiting?

Comment: @Braiam Then there should be a notification for "Your question was closed".

Comment: Which bring us to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/213575

Comment: WHAT? How... how it is a dupe of that question?!

Comment: @nicael I know. The other question is *related* at most.

Comment: @Mooseman - did you mean a comment appears and then disappears? You don't mention it disappears. (checking if mine is a dupe of yours: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251439/new-comment-notification-appears-and-dissapears-when-moderator-marks-q-as-dupe). Or are you talking about "notification" only? Cheers

Comment: @James It never appears, really. Only the notifications.

Comment: @Mooseman Possibly you've just not seen it? I've just witnessed it reading a new question (not my Q so got no notification). I'd guess the two occur from the same action. animuson has updated the question to include my observations.

Comment: The comment can be used to notify the OP that the question is being closed - because SE don't notify owners when their question is closed...

Comment: I wonder whether the same thing happens when a normal 3K user (i.e., not a gold badge holder) casts the fifth close vote on a question, and it is a VTC as duplicate vote with a dup target that hasn’t been cited by any of the first four votes.  I.e., will it create a “possible duplicate” comment that will immediately be swept up in the question-closure process?

Comment: In any case, the ‘‘dupehammer’’ behavior is still there — I just experienced it.  Is this even on a list of things to get fixed in six to eight years?

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні no, this does not have review tag, so not even 60-80 years.