# New comment notification appears and disappears when Dupehammer marks Q as dupe (seemingly)

Tags: bug, moderation, automatic-comments

*Potential bug / FYI*

Noticed it on SO, but reporting on MSE as it's likely present on other sites, if it is a bug.

---

I was reading a new question on SO, it had no answers or comments, then the "*1 new comment*" text appeared.
When I clicked the "new comment link"  there was no comment, instead a blank space appeared on the page where a comment would have been, about the size of a comment (as I recall).

However, I did not receive any message/notification (i.e. "Error retrieving comment").

I refreshed the page and it updated to show it had been marked as a dupe (by John Conde).
(All comment *shenanigans* disappeared now too, no space, link, text, etc)

When *non*-Dupehammer flag as dupe, there is an auto comment (e.g. "possible dupe of [link]").

So I'm thinking that *possibly* when a Dupehammer flags as dupe, it initially invokes the same script which actions the auto comment for *non*-Dupehammer users , but then doesn't complete, or some conditional stops/reverts it, as it discovers user is a Dupehammer.

Or, maybe John Conde added and deleted a comment, and then marked as dupe. But if so, he's bl--dy fast!

---

Obviously no biggie at all, but thought I'd mention it in case it is a bug.

(The [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088950/php-comparing-times) where it occurred is likely irrelevant)

Comment: I thought he was a mod, my bad. Still stands, just mod should have been Dupehammer (have edited my Q). This Q *seems* to not be a dupe of the other one as it states "Dupehammer creates comment *notification*" - I'm reporting it quickly adds and removes it on the page body. Maybe that also happens, and can be incorporated into Mooseman's question. Have asked for clarification in other Q.

Comment: His report focused more on the creation of the *inbox notification*. Because the comment was created, he, as the owner of the post, got notified of a new comment on his post (which was deleted immediately when it was created and thus there's no comment to view when you visit the post via the notification). Your report focuses on a different notification. Because the comment was created, you were notified below the post that there was a new comment to load (which again was deleted immediately and causes nothing new to load when you click on it).

Comment: @animuson Yeah. Both mine and Mooseman's observations  likely/possibly happen from the same actions. If so, what's the best way to link the two Qs? Mooseman adds this info to his?

Comment: Updated that request with better information.