# Remove comment notifications when I load the question

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, notification-bar

When I post a question on which somebody comments, I get a notification. This is good.

However, if I visit the question *without* clicking on the notification and loading the comment url (Such as this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/812735?noredirect=1), the notification still appears unread.

Please make loading the question (and fetching the comments assuming the question is still loaded) valid activity to mark said notification read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with this. There are dozens of other reasons for you to visit your question other than reading this comment. If you happen to be visiting your question for such a purpose, you may easily miss the comment, in particular if your question has many comments.

Of course, if for example your question has neither answers nor other comments at this point, you are very likely to visit because of the comment and even if you just want to see the views go up or [check whether your question hasn’t been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554), you are likely to notice the comment. However, I do not see a good point to draw a line here and even if one did, I would consider this to do more harm than good, because of an inconsistent behaviour and the resulting confusion.