# Why does "question closed as duplicate" not qualify as an inbox notification?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

I asked [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21146/why-does-mathjax-not-render-in-comments-on-the-mobile-app) today. I went out for a while then came back and found notifications of upvotes to an answer. I then looked at the question again and noticed it had been closed as a duplicate. But I had **no notification of that**.

After editing that question to make it less of a duplicate, I came here to ask: why is this so? Why do I get notifications of edits to questions, comments, answers, but not of questions being put on hold / closed as [whatever the reason might be]?

I would like to be notified if a question gets closed, especially if it is an old question I do not look at any longer, because without the notification I might not ever see the closure.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate - but the answers over there are only people stating good reasons to implement this feature, and none of them disagrees with the request. Actually, the only one that did was deleted. Luckily [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258281/269069) has a temporary solution, if I manage to use that script. But still, I'm not too convinced about clicking `This solved my problem` up there…

Comment: That's what answers on unimplemented feature requests look like. They're supporting arguments. The text in the 'this solved my problem" box is not really appropriate for FR questions but you can interpret it as "this is the same feature I'm requesting".