# Why don't I get an email when my question is put on hold?

Tags: feature-request

I get email notifications when someone answers or comments on one of my questions, but not when one of my questions is put on hold.  That's an event I'd like to know about!  Why am I not notified?

Comment: It's probably to reduce the amount of whining.

Comment: Btw the question you asked that sparked this would probably have been better asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So now you're not only ignoring differences, but deleting comments about them?  I guess I won't be notified when you delete this comment either.

Answer (score 4):

You only get email notifications for things that send you SE notifications... and [question closure is not one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed?rq=1).

Jeff Atwood had posted a (heavily downvoted) answer there which seems to have gotten deleted, but the gist of his reasoning was that it would a) increase complaining b) be too many inbox notifications. No-one really liked his reasoning though.