# No notification when question put on hold

Tags: discussion, notifications, on-hold

I asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81442/glue-to-stick-aluminium-to-plastic) on a SE site I'm not particularly familiar with, which got put on hold because part of the question asked for a product recommendation which is apparently off limits - fair enough, and silly me. No argument from me.

However, I got no notification - meaning here something in the 'inbox' or similar - it had been put on hold (I did get a notification for the one answer). Had I got a notification, I would simply have deleted the limb of the question (the recommendation) that was off-topic. It's a bit late now.

Related: [Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed/258281#258281) - that is slightly different as it would be good to know as soon as your question gets put on hold, not only after (I'm told) 6 days when it is finally closed. Though I would clearly support getting notified when it is closed too.

Is there a reason questioners do not get alerted if their question gets put on hold? I'm asking this on meta.SE as I suspect this issue is pervasive to all sites.

Comment: And also take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258281) as a workaround.

Comment: @nicael Stupid question: is 'on hold' the same as 'closed'? If so, then yes this is a dupe. If not, then it is related.

Comment: On hold becomes closed after 5 days, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question

Comment: @nicael OK so I am asking for something a little different - being notified when it goes on hold, as opposed to closed, when it is too late, but they are certainly related. I will edit.

Comment: Nono, the "on hold" is technically closed too, just with another name. The another question is asking exactly the same thing (not later than 6 days), so yours's a dupe.

Comment: Oh I see. Can you mark it as a dupe again and I will close it.

Comment: It's not too late. "On hold/Closed" is a state to prevent answers from being added to a problematic question. The _idea_ is that the Asker, if possible, can use that time to "fix" the question. Go ahead and edit out the bit that made it off-topic.