# Is it necessary to flag negative questions for non-critical reasons?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

Negatively scored questions are automatically deleted after 30 days. If a negative question is simply a bad question (not spam, not abusive and not a duplicate) should I even bother flagging it for either being too broad, too opinionated or not specific enough?

Why flag if it'll be gone anyways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closing the question will:

1. Prevent low quality answers from being posted to the question (which may also end up preventing the entire question from being deleted).
2. Give information to the post author on the specific problems with the question, along with advice on how to address those problems.
3. Allow the question to be automatically deleted even sooner, in the event that the owner doesn't address the problems with the post.

Comment: *Give information to the post author on the specific problems with the question, along with advice on how to address those problems.* – [Only when closing as a duplicate or custom off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554) or if the author looks at the question again. Otherwise you have to leave a custom comment.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Even if they don't get an inbox message, the close reason is still providing information about the problems with their question and information about how to address those problems.