# Email notifications not working about question edits and changes

Tags: support, stack-overflow, notifications, email

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357560/install-all-local-extensions-in-all-dev-containers-automatically) in Stack Overflow and my question was closed. I hoped that I would receive email notifications about changes and when the question was closed but I didn't receive email notifications. Is it ok?

I looked for emails in my Gmail, in the spam category and I checked my profile notification settings to see if my notification is disabled, but they are not.

Comment: **To close voters:** This question is on-topic here. The close dialog specifically states that the close reason is not for questions that can be applied to other sites, even if they focus on one specific site. This question can definitely be equally applied to any other site in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in setting that email notifications were sent daily by default, not immediately like I had hoped for.

[image]

After I set it to 3hrs the problem somewhat solved for me, and now I at least will receive notification after 3hrs.

Answer (score 3):

Changes to the question (answers, edits, comments, closure, etc.) do trigger *inbox notifications*. (Some always did, some like closure were [added later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-is-closed).)

However, **email** notifications, even when enabled, are sent only for unread inbox items. Once you read an item in the inbox (either by clicking it or explicitly marking as read by clicking the envelope sign) it won't be sent in the email notification.

So most likely, in your case, you marked the notification as read in your site inbox, hence they were not sent to your email.

Comment: Yeah, It seems that this problem is related to "email notification settings" -> "Your Communities" -> "Inbox" set to Daily and notifications in the inbox are younger than 24h. I changed it to 3h.

Comment: This too, yeah.